# synchronization of two image topics (infrared stream)

Tags: synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to sync the left and right infrared image topic  from my Intel RealSense R200 camera. Currently, I have managed to subscribe to the individual infrared topic (left and right) with its camera info through using [image_transport::CameraSubscriber](http://docs.ros.org/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1CameraSubscriber.html).
My next goal would be to sync and publish both the left and right infrared stream as well as their camera info. How do I go about achieving the goal? Is it through using [image_transport::SubscriberFilter](http://docs.ros.org/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1SubscriberFilter.html) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248254/synchronization-of-two-image-topics-(infrared-stream)/) by [timku](https://answers.ros.org/users/28140/timku/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-18**:
Question answered? Please mark it as such by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it through using [image_transport::SubscriberFilter](http://docs.ros.org/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1SubscriberFilter.html) ?

Yes. From the documentation you linked:

> This class wraps [Subscriber](http://docs.ros.org/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1Subscriber.html) as a "filter" compatible with the [message_filters](http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/c++/namespacemessage__filters.html) package. It acts as a highest-level filter, simply passing messages from an image transport subscription through to the filters which have connected to it.

You should then be able to use the [ExactTime](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ExactTime_Policy) or [Approximate Time](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy) policies from `message_filters` to synchronise your topics.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0